# Can I copy app data from an old iPhone backup to a new, set-up iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I recently got a new iPhone. I backed up my old iPhone in iTunes, and then set up my new iPhone as a restore-from-backup. However, I was just looking at my new iPhone and realized some apps failed to copy over.

Is there a way to copy the app data from the old iPhone to the new-but-already-setup iPhone, or do I need to start over?

I know I can download the apps, but can I transfer the data? Part of this is game data that I know does not live in iCloud or any server.

Answer (score 1):

After iOS 8, according to [this document by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136), app contents are no longer backed up by iTunes. I suggest using [iMazing](https://imazing.com/) to backup your old phone, and restore it on your new phone to get the app content.